# Is there a Gram Schmidt on an inner product with nonzero constraint?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $(V, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be an infinite dimensional inner product space.

Gram-Schmidt says that for all $n$ we can find $n$ vectors $v_1,...,v_n$ so that $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=0$ for all $i\neq j$. I am curious - can we change the $0$? That is:

> Can we find $n$ distinct vectors so that $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=4$ for all $i\neq j$, for example?

It is tricky. Gram-Schmidt just uses bilinearity which is insufficient here - as the zero bilinear form shows that the answer to the question above is no if we just require bilinearity.

Comment: This isn't that tricky.  An inner product is not "the zero bilinear form".  We have nonzero results when a nonzero vector is taken for both arguments of a (real) inner product.

Comment: @hardmath It's not clear to me how you can find $n$ of them, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that you find the regular orthonormal basis $u_1, ..., u_n$, with $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle=\delta_{i,j}$. Then let's construct $$U=\sum_{i=1}^nu_i$$
Notice that $\langle U,U\rangle=n$. Now add $CU$, $C\in\mathbb R$, to the orthonormal basis vectors $$v_i=u_i+CU$$
Then you have $$\langle v_i, v_j\rangle=\langle u_i+CU, u_j+CU\rangle\\=\langle u_i, u_j\rangle+\langle u_i, CU\rangle+\langle CU, u_j\rangle+\langle CU, CU\rangle\\=\delta_{i,j}+2C+C^2n$$
Now just choose $2C+C^2n=4$ and you get your desired vectors.

Comment: Question, what about negative values? What if instead of $4$ it was $-4$?

Comment: @user953480 If $\langle v_i,v_i\rangle=1$ and $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=a$, then with $u=\sum v_i$, we have $0<\langle u,u\rangle = n+n(n-1)a$, so necessarily $a>-\frac1{n-1}$.

Comment: Start from @HagenvonEitzen 's comment. Then you can repeat the same procedure as above, but you need to scale all vectors by an additional scaling factor.